# Need advise on using maps within an Android App that I want to develop

Tags: android

I'm considering building an Android app for my HTC phone that contains tour guides to attractions in London.  An Example, a guide that shows information about Jack The Ripper area, where the killings took place, having a start and a finish marker on a map, and a route showing areas of interest.  The user would look at the map, and follow the route from start to finish.

Question for the more experience developer - as I've zero Android app dev experience, how easy an app does this sound?

I was considering getting maps off the net, cropping them and customising them for each of the tour.  Can you get free maps off the web, legally?

Or use Google Map (or something similar), and customising them to each tour.

I hope that I've described my idea as clearly as possible, I look forward to your replies.

p.s. this app is what I'm thinking about minus the audio at every waypoint: https://market.android.com/details?id=hu.pocketguide.bundle.London_lite&feature=also_installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google forbids modifying or caching their maps(by means other then standart) as I remember. So consider using Open Street Maps with the help of free or paid library.

Comment: I downloaded Budget London (https://market.android.com/details?id=com.objectiq.budgetlondon) app who use Google Maps to display a marker from a link onto the map.  Is this easy to do?

Comment: “Spartans don't ask how many the enemy are, but where they are.”

Comment: Is there a resource you know that you can point me to?

Comment: http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/android/add-ons/google-apis/ that's the ultimate resource.